# Is there an efficient python way to window the data?

Tags: python

I have a time-series data that has 45000 rows and 30 columns. I want to split this data up into rolling windows of length 150 along the rows and compute some statistics for each window.

Basically, this means I first take rows 0 to 149 and compute mean followed by std for each column. I then take rows 1 to 150 and again compute mean and std for each column separately. I stack vectors of means and std for each column horizontally.

At the moment I have the following function:

```
def statFeaturesWindowed(data):
    dataLen = data.shape[0]
    count = 0
    winSize = 150

    ftVect = np.empty((1, 60))

    while count+winSize <= dataLen:
        if not count % 1000:
            print("Row {} of {}".format(count, dataLen-winSize))
        dataWin = data[count:count+winSize,:] # data window
        means = np.mean(dataWin, axis = 0) # mean
        stDev = np.std(dataWin, axis = 0) # standard deviation           

        tempVect = np.hstack((means, stDev)).T
        ftVect = np.vstack((ftVect, tempVect))
        count+=1

    np.delete(ftVect, (1), 0)

    return ftVect
```

However, this code is super slow and slows down as the output matrix becomes larger and larger. At the moment running this for 45000 lines takes roughly 5 minutes. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this, http://www.rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!